# Drag and drop view between pages of UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, drag-and-drop, uipageviewcontroller

I have been trying to implement drag and drop between pages of UIPageViewController, like when you move your apps between the pages of your iPhone's home screen. The problem is that when I start dragging the view and switch to the next page, the view freezes and becomes undraggable. Do you have any idea how NOT to stop the touch event when switching between pages?

Comment: can you post any code ? Perhaps you have some instructions in the viewWillAppear() of your different views which block your main thread.

Comment: Yes, here are the two classes I use to setup the page view controller and handle the drag. I use an UIPageViewController with tableviews on each page. I want to drag a cell from one page to another.

http://pastebin.com/dtdGDwzM
http://pastebin.com/91dwjJkf

Comment: I see JiraRestClientAPI.sharedInstance.getAllAvailableBoards in your viewWillAppear(). So when you swipe your view, before displaying you launch API instructions.

Comment: Same result if they are in viewDidLoad(). Any other ideas?

Comment: can you comment **if issue.hasAvatar == true {...}** in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method of AgileIssuesViewController.

Comment: Nothing different happens. I think the reason is NOT in the cells' data. Any other ideas? :)

Comment: @scourGINHO, I know this was long time ago, but did you manage to make it working? Maybe you can provide some examples if you still have access to the code

Comment: Any solution on this?